# Crew requirements for sailing a ketch

Tags: sailing, water-sports

When sailing a traditional twin mast ketch, what are the recommended crew requirements?

Let's assume the following for simplicity:

1. Captain has 6-pack maritime license.
2. Captain and passengers total 5 people.
3. Crew has 1-2 years sailing experience.
4. Sailing within 20 miles of shore, not in commercial shipping lane.
5. Boat bow to stern is 45 feet.
6. Prevailing wind is 10-15 knots, seas 4-5 feet at the bell.
7. Visibility is 5 nautical miles.

What are the responsibilities of each crew member?

Comment: Skill matters a lot. If you're asking this question, I'll guess you're at the low end of the scale.

Comment: Setting matters a lot. Blue-water sailing in heavy weather is different than lake sailing on in fair weather.

Comment: And, of course, size matters.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've actually grown up on the water, but wanted to get some sailing questions seeded. Changed the question to make it more pointed and useful.

Comment: @Dangeranger Yeah, I assumed thats why the private beta is so small...to seed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every boat is different, and every crew is different. There is no set standard. Some people go single-handed on a ketch, some have fairly large crew. [Bernard Moitessier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Moitessier) used to sail a 39-foot ketch single-handed and with his wife.

Comment: is right. Can you raise & trim sails from the cockpit? I've sailed a 35' New Haven Sharpie (nominally a ketch) solo by holding a sheet in each hand, and letting the rudder do what it wants.

Comment: Bernard Moitessier lost three ships.